# SQL printing error message with bad record code

Tags: sql, printing, triggers, declare

Working with  SQL Server 2005
Creating Trigger which checks if inserting not already exist.
Having problem getting record parameter, there is the code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER t_MFShiftTypeOperation ON [CAST$MFShiftTypeOperation]
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE AS
```

IF @@ROWCOUNT=1
BEGIN

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted AS I
           JOIN CAST$MFShiftTypeOperation AS STO
           ON ((I.ShiftTypeCode = STO.ShiftTypeCode AND 
                I.PackCode = STO.PackCode) OR
                I.RegisterAppCode = STO.RegisterAppCode))
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Bad_PackCode AS EmpUserCode_t
    SET @Bad_PackCode = SELECT TOP(1) PackCode FROM inserted --there is error

    ROLLBACK TRAN
    PRINT  'Оperation with '+ @Bad_PackCode +' already exist'
END
```

END

when I'm trying to execute code, it throws me error message:

```
 Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure t_MFShiftTypeOperation, Line 16
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.
```

Can someone explain where is mistake, or suggest better solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
SET @Bad_PackCode = SELECT TOP(1) PackCode FROM inserted --there is error
```

to this:

```
SELECT TOP(1) @Bad_PackCode=PackCode FROM inserted
```